# Is there a general rule of thumb for multiple <br /> tags?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a webpage run on php with a few tables, input boxes, and a form. The design is pretty basic but, I use various `<br />` tags when needed. Sometimes I may have two or three in a row so the spacing looks better.

Is there a rule of thumb on what to do when one uses multiple `<br />` tags? Do most people just append them on the same line of code, or have each `<br />` tag on its own line?

Comment: using as many as you like is fine but more will increase output size, when you could just increase a div size or specific id's attributes with css. I only tend to use them to clear a float left/right `<br clear="all"/>`

Comment: You should probably be enclosing in <p> tags or whatever is logical and using CSS to space them

Comment: I added an answer, then I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br - removed my answer as this is definitely a duplicate :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of adding extra HTML, it is widely accepted that the better approach be to [separate content from presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content) by using CSS to add space (for example `padding` or `margin`) between elements instead of `<br/>` tags.

Answer (score 9):

actually the rule of thumb is not to use `<br />` tags at all for styling. you should be using css to create margins between things not html markup.

Answer (score 7):

There isn't a rule of thumb about line breaks -- use what makes sense.

That said, multiple line breaks can be a sign that you're using the wrong approach; they usually don't make any sense at all. If you're using line breaks to create white space or to position layout elements, you should be using css padding or margins instead (or positioning). Paragraphs should be enclosed in `p` tags instead. Tabular data should use `table`.

Also -- if you're making **HTML**, the tag is `<br>`

> In XHTML, the XML syntactic requirements dictate that this must be
>   made explicit using either an explicit end tag, as above, or the empty
>   element syntax. This is achieved by inserting a slash at the end of
>   the start tag immediately before the right angle bracket.

reference: [HTML 5 Draft reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-br-element)

A note about w3Schools: you should be aware the w3Schools is not affiliated with the w3c standards body (the publishers of the HTML specification), nor with any other standards body or browser vendor. Some of the information on that site is incorrect.

For a better reference, you should always check the spec ([html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), [html4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/) [you should just use 5]). Other reliable resources include browser vendors or language publishers. For example, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), [php.net](http://www.php.net/), [ASP.net on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.aspx), etc. w3Schools **cannot** be more authoritative or accurate than these resources.

**More Reading**

- *Serving XML as text/html considered harmful* by Ian Hickson - http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml
- *Empty elements in SGML, HTML, XML, and XHTML* by Jukka Korpela - http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/empty.html
- w3c HTML validator - http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 0):

For once I have the short answer. BR tags are for line-breaks in text. That is all.