# Is the <wbr> element semantic HTML? What about in a microdata context?

Tags: semantic-web, word-wrap, semantic-markup, microdata, wbr

In short, this is bad web development and UX:

[image]

But solving it by using CSS3 word breaking [(code & demo)](http://jsbin.com/uripod/5/edit) can lead to an 'awkward whitespace' situation, and strange cut-offs — here's an example of both:

[image]

Maybe it's not such a big deal, and the [UX perspective of it is here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31764/hyphenating-urls-and-email-addresses-that-would-overflow-their-container), but let's look at the semantics of [one of the solutions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/31767/21154):

> You could ... use the `<wbr>` element to indicate an optional word
>   break opportunity. This will tell the browser to insert a line break
>   as necessary to flow onto a new line inside the container.

The first question: is using `<wbr>` semantic HTML? (Does it at least degrade gracefully?)

In either case, it seems that being un-semantic in the general sense is a small price to pay for good UX functionality.

However, the second quesiton is about the big picture:

Are there any [schema.org](http://schema.org) (microdata/RFDa) ramifications to consider when using `<wbr>` to split up an email address? **Will it still be valid there?**

Comment: Why would someone downvote this question now after it has been answered? (Especially without explaining.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `wbr` element is [defined in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-wbr-element). So it's fine to use it. If it's used right (= according to the definition in the spec), you may call it also "semantic use".

I don't think that there would be any problems in combination with micordata/RDFa. Usually you'd provide the URL in an attribute anyway, which can't contain `wbr` elements of course: `<a href="mailto:foo@example.com">foo<wbr>@example<wbr>.com</a>`.

For element content I'd guess (didn't check though) that microdata/RDFa parsers should use the text content *without* markup resp. understand what is markup and what is text, otherwise e.g. a FOAF name would be `<abbr>Dr.</abbr> Foo` instead of `Dr. Foo`.

So you can bet that microdata/RDFa parsers know HTML ;), and therefor it shouldn't be a problem to use its elements.

Comment: Agree with everything, but `<br>` is also [not really semantic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br) — so where does that leave `<wbr>`?

Comment: @Baumr: `br` is perfectly "semantic" *if* it is used right (= according to [its definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element)). It's (exclusively!) for content where line breaks are important for the meaning. Think of poems or addresses.