# How to add padding at bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I have a website here

http://trentmcminn.com/

For some reason the bottom of the page (the word Barney) is slightly cutoff by the fixed position footer.  I am trying to add padding to the bottom of the body by this but it is not doing what I am trying.  I am not sure what is going on.  ANy help would be appreciated.

```
body {
padding-bottom: 100px;
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Side note: regarding the layout of your site, you may want to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the absolutely positioned footer is overlapping with column layout.
You could either reduce the size of the columns and give them a negative bottom margin, or apply a padding to the columns like for example:

```
div#grid.col-4 div.column {
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: i think you should mark it correct, if you are satisfied with the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
html{ padding-bottom: 25px;}
```

This pads 25 pixels to the bottom of every page that uses the css that includes this tag. All pages should have   tags enclosing the content. This is a better option then body because dynamic content and floating divs may not give the desired effect within the body. It also is handy in that it will give you a constant padding effect on all pages within the site.

Comment: (Welcome to SO! Make "code"-parts like `div`s stand out enclosing them in `\`"back-ticks"\``. Then, it should be "…option *than* `body`…".) Care to explain choosing padding over margin?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the margin of you `div#grid.albums div.item` from `30px` to `50px`, for example.
That will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, It works, but I dont want to change the margin between the items.  Thought there would be a simple way to add padding to the bottom of <body>.  I have done it before, just not sure why on this site its not working

Answer (score 0):

Update following style rule:

```
div#grid.albums div.item {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```