# Vertically align image with text within <li>

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align text with an image (or vice-versa?). Here's some code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">col-md-3
    <ul>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"><p>Text Text Text</p></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"><p>Text</p></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"><p>Text Text Text Text</p></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"><p>Text Text</p></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"><p>Text Text Text Text Text</p></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"><p>Text</p></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"><p>Text Text</p></li>
    </ul>
  {# 3 more columns like this #}
</div>
```

also **CSS**:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div ul li {
    display: table-row;
}    

img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

also, might be important all images are the same fixed size, let's say 60x60 like in example and I can **not** use it as a background.
How can I align it? Thanks.

Update: as were pointed out, I'm looking for text to be in the middle of the right edge of the picture, thanks.

Comment: 'vertically align text with an image' doesn't describe what you want well enough, how do you want them aligned?

Comment: Why are you using <p> tag inside li. This will move the text to the next line. and also float left property of image can be problematic here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My solution works with one line of text as well as multiple lines.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/n5LR8/) *Tested on:* IE10, IE9, IE8, Chrome, FF, Safari

**HTML:** same as you posted

I'm assuming you meant middle alignment. if not: use `top` | `bottom` instead of `middle`

**CSS**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}

div ul li
{
    margin: 5px;
}    

img
{
    vertical-align: middle; /* | top | bottom */
}
div ul li p
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; /* | top | bottom */
}
```

Comment: @JonP use one paragraph, and `<br/>` tags to break it to lines, and it will work. (as showed in the fiddle)

Comment: `<br />` are not semanticaly the same as `<p>`. Furthur more What if the description is pulled from a database containing more than one parragraph. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br

Comment: it's really not a problem. the only thing that is needed for this solution to work, is to enclose all the text (whatever the form) within an `inline-block` element (I used a `p` with `disply: inline-block`), that will be aligned with the image. the content can be in different `p` tags, or whatever.. as long as all of it is enclosed inside a `inline-block` container.

Comment: Worked for me, awesome

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `<p>` tag and the `float:left` from `img` and you got it.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/BA2Lc/

Answer (score 1):

I am not a big fan of using those table display options, had some bad cross-browser experiences with them.

Seems to me you could use line-height here. Something like this:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div ul li {
    line-height: 60px;
}    

img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qjSpj/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `<p>` style from the default display to inline:

```
p {display: inline}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vertical-align: top;` declaration on the `li` element. But you will need to use a clearfix since you're floating the image.

Answer (score 0):

I just added vertical-align:middle/top/bottom; to the images and worked.