# Pre text format in width

Tags: html, css, cordova, topcoat

I am using topcoat `css` on a `cordova` mobile app. I want pre-text to fit within `width` and not `word-wrap`.

http://codepen.io/civilwar/pen/JEebd

I have text that I want to keep the return characters between paragraphs. I do not want to keep the width of the text.  To get around this issue I have my pre text to be in a div that has word wrap break word.  This converts the text to only appear within the width of the mobile app ( i.e. I don't have to scroll to the right).  Getting rid of word wrap break word makes the pre text go out to its original width.  I want to disable word wrap but keep my pre-text within the `width` of the app how do I do that?

Comment: Add code to the question... other than link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jyjrm)**

Just this `CSS`

```
.summary > pre {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

good luck!

Comment: this fixes the width but removes the spacing between paragraphs.  I want to keep the spacing between paragraphs

Comment: @user1795480 just add line-height: 25px; or whatever you want. Perhaps this was not part of the question.

Comment: close enough I just had all my text convert return lines to <br>

Comment: @user1795480 <br> is not recommended solution each time you add new text you have to add a <br>. Suppose you have a dynamic text then adding <br> seems not right to me. see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br