# How HTML br can replaced with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When ever I want to use new line in HTML code, I do use `<br>` but when I got code performance testing and been through on some of good practice on HTML. I found that m totally doing wrong when using `<br>` for new line.

I've been through with this
 [article.](http://line25.com/articles/youre-doing-it-wrong-common-html-tag-misuse)

Looking forward to know from community, is this good way or any other thing recommended to use in place of `<br>` (Like any CSS/javascript Trick)

If there is any other way, can you please refer via code sample.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1726103/1612146) might help you.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're actually asking...

Comment: [Do not use `<br>` to increase the gap between lines of text; use the CSS margin property or the `<p>` element.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

Comment: @Jeroen, what's unclear in this about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I found that m totally doing wrong when using `<br>` for new line

Not necessarily. That is, after all, its express (and only) purpose: Starting a new line. For instance, in poetry a line break is frequently meaningful and yet doesn't start a new paragraph, so:

```html
What's in a name? that which we call a rose
<br>By any other name would smell as sweet;
```

...is a perfectly reasonable way to write those two lines of Romeo and Juliet.

But if you want to start a new *paragraph*, you wouldn't use `<br>`, you'd end the current paragraph and start a new one:

```
<p>This is one paragraph</p>
<p>This is another</p>
```

Similarly, you wouldn't typically use it to break things up in a container like a `div`; instead, you'd end one `div` and start another:

```
<div>This is one div</div>
<div>This is another</div>
```

You can also use CSS to style elements that are normally inline or inline-block to be block like `div` elements are, but that's not *usually* a good idea (there are always exceptions).

If you want to add space between elements, that's what the `padding` and `margin` CSS properties are for.