# How to make reverse asterisk Triangle with JavaScript using 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop

I want to make a reverse triangle using 'for' loop, which should look like this:

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

This what I got:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

And this is my code:

```js
function rightTriangle(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (var j = n - 1; j >= i; j--) {
      document.write('*');
    }
    document.write('<br>');
  }
}
rightTriangle(5);
```

Please help me out with this task, I would be so appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Add the below code to leave the intendation

```
for(var k=0; k<i; k++){
    document.write("&nbsp;");
}
```

```js
function rightTriangle (n) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for(var k=0; k<i; k++){
          document.write("&nbsp;");
        }
        for (var j = n-1; j >= i; j--) {
            document.write('*');
        }
        document.write('<br>');
    }
}
rightTriangle(5);
```

```css
html{
  font-family:monospace;
}
```

Comment: ...and probably a fixed-width font.

Comment: Thanks buddy! That was extremely helpful! God bless you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function rightTriangle(n) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
      if(j>=i) document.write('*');
      else document.write('&nbsp&nbsp');
    }
    document.write('<br>');
  }
}
rightTriangle(5);
```

Comment: you don't have to use the double space. It is issue with font. (+1 to your solution)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Bruno! That was extremely helpful! God bless you!

Comment: @NurekeDuisekeyev please if the answer is correct please mark it like the right one to close the post

Answer (score 0):

#### Algo

- Create n*n matrix with 2 values, `" "` and `"*"`
- In html `" "` has no effect as extra spaces are trimmed. You will have to use `&nbsp;`, unicode value for single space.
- Now loop and add necessary parts to string.
- Since you need reverse triangle, spaces will come first. You can loop in ascending fashion with value of `i` denoting spaces and `n-i` denoting "*"

```js
function rightTriangle(n) {
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j< i; j++){
      html += "&nbsp;";
    }
    for(var k = 0; k< n-i; k++){
      html += "*"
    }
    html +="<br/>"
  }
  document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = html
}
rightTriangle(5);
```

```css
.content {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

#### string.repeat

```js
function rightTriangle(n) {
  var html = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    html += "&nbsp;".repeat(i) + "*".repeat(n - i) + "</br>"
  }
  document.querySelector('.content').innerHTML = html
}
rightTriangle(5);
```

```css
.content {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"></div>
```

Also note that using [document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) and [< br/>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br) are considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most simple solution:

```
 const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();

 let n = parseInt(prompt("Enter the number of rows: "));

 let string = "";
 function printPyramid(row) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    string += " ".repeat(i) + "*".repeat(n - i);
    string += "\n";
  }
 }
 printPyramid(n);
 process.stdout.write(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This code must work on ur terminal or any online js compiler.

// 3 for loops are used here; i for rows, j for spaces , k for printing stars

```
function invertedRightTri(n){
    var str="";
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){       
        for(j=n-i;j<n;j++){
            str+=" ";
        }
        for (k=0;k<n-i+1;k++){
            str+="*";
        }
        str+="\n";
    }
    return str;
}
var ans=invertedRightTri(5);
console.log(ans);
```