# Write multiple strings on the same id

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

Let's say I have the input of 'Fred'.
How can I print it so that it looks like this?

```
Character List:

F

r

e

d
```

And that it is all being written to a paragraph element in html with the `id = 'msg2'`

So far all that I can get it to write is either F or d

Apologies, forgot to include code

```
function start () {
    var vName = document.getElementById('custname').value;
    var vLength = processString(vName);

    document.getElementById('msg1').innerHTML = vName;
    document.getElementById('msg2').innerHTML = vLength;
}

function processString (pString) {

    for (i = 0; i < pString.length; i++) {
        t = i + 1
        var vReturnName = ('Character list: <br />' + (pString.substring(i, t)))
    }
    return (vReturnName);
}
```

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: ID **must be** unique.

Comment: @Jai I forgot to add the code. I have added it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has few issues:

- `var vReturnName =`  inside loop will always have last value as you are overriding it. Move declaration outside loop and the use `vReturnName +=`  to append
- `(pString.substring(i, t))` This will give you single character but you are not adding `<br/>` after it and so you will have no line-breaks. Also you can use `string.charAt` instead of it.
- `for (i = 0;`  Any variable defined without `var|let|const` becomes global.

```js
function start() {
  var vName = document.getElementById('custname').value;
  var vLength = processString(vName);

  document.getElementById('msg1').innerHTML = vName;
  document.getElementById('msg2').innerHTML = vLength;
}

function processString(pString) {
  var vReturnName = 'Character list: <br />'
  for (i = 0; i < pString.length; i++) {
    t = i + 1
    vReturnName += (pString.substring(i, t) + "<br/>")
  }
  return (vReturnName);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="custname" />
<button onclick="start()">Process String</button>
<div id="msg1"></div>
<div id="msg2"></div>
```

#### Alternate solution:

```js
function start() {
  var vName = document.getElementById('custname').value;
  var vLength = processString(vName);

  document.getElementById('msg1').innerHTML = vName;
  document.getElementById('msg2').innerHTML = vLength;
}

function processString(pString) {
  var vReturnName = wrapInP('Character list:')
  for (var i = 0; i < pString.length; i++) {
    vReturnName += wrapInP(pString.charAt(i))
  }
  return vReturnName;
}

function wrapInP(str){
  return "<p>" + str + "</p>"
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="custname" />
<button onclick="start()">Process String</button>
<div id="msg1"></div>
<div id="msg2"></div>
```

#### References:

- [Is it sometimes bad to use <BR />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br)
- [string.charAt(x) or string[x]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943726/string-charatx-or-stringx)

Comment: So, you are effectively giving each letter in the string its own temporary paragraph element?

Comment: Yes. You can either do that or have a `div` as they are block element. This prevents us from using `<br/>`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I had this in the back of my mind, but no idea how to.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string and use forEach to loop over the array then create new element and just put it in the DOM:

```js
let str = "FRED";

str.split('').forEach(s => {
  let p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = s;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
})
```

```css
p{border-bottom:solid 1px #c8c8c8;}
```

Comment: @Rajesh Apologies. I forgot to include the code. I have done that now

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get `array` of each character.

Use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to get the string concatenated with `<br><br>`

```js
var name = "Fred";
var newName = name.split('').join('<br><br>');
document.getElementById('msg2').innerHTML = newName;
```

```html
<div id='msg2'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to split up the text and append it to the div like so:

```js
var string = 'Fred';
var characters = string.split('');
for(var i=0; i< characters.length; i++)
{
  $('#msg2').append(characters[i]+'<br/>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = 'msg2'></div>
```

If using Pure JS:

```js
    var string = 'Fred';
    var characters = string.split('');
    for(var i=0; i< characters.length; i++)
    {
      document.getElementById('msg2').innerHTML+=characters[i]+'<br/>';
    }
```

```html
    <div id = 'msg2'></div>
```