# Insert line break every 3 lines in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm still a newbie at javascript so I want to create a script that inserts a line break after every 3 lines. So here's my code I got so far

```js
var num = `http://url.com
http://url2test.com
http://url3nag.com
http://url4lalala.com
http://url5papapapapa.com
http://url6ddadadadad.com
http://url7etet.com
http://url8testtest.com`;
var newNum = num.toString().match(/.{3}/g).join('</br>');
console.log(newNum);
```

It is doing it wrong. It seems to be inserting every 3characters instead of lines. Can anyone help me fix the code?

Comment: First you need to find the line endings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `replace` function. Try the below code.

```js
var num = `http://url.com
http://url2test.com
http://url3nag.com
http://url4lalala.com
http://url5papapapapa.com
http://url6ddadadadad.com
http://url7etet.com
http://url8testtest.com`;
var newNum = num.replace(/(.*\n.*\n.*\n)/g, '$1<br>');
console.log(newNum);
```

### EDIT

I have made a few changes to the RegEx in the code below. This will allow you to specify the number of lines between which `<br>` need to be added.

```js
var num = `http://url.com
http://url2test.com
http://url3nag.com
http://url4lalala.com
http://url5papapapapa.com
http://url6ddadadadad.com
http://url7etet.com
http://url8testtest.com`;
var newNum = num.replace(/((.*\n){3})/g, '$1<br>');
console.log(newNum);
```

In the above RegEx, the `.*` will match all characters till the end of line and the `\n` will match the new line character.

`(.*\n){3}`

I have enclosed this in parenthesis to mark it as a group and used `{3}` to indicate that the preceding group repeats 3 times.

`((.*\n){3})`

Then the whole RegEx is enclosed in a parenthesis to use it as the first matched group that can be referenced in the `replace` section using `$1`.

You can replace the `{3}` with any number.

Comment: can you explain your code? cause I sometimes want to change the number of lines to insert like every 50lines

Comment: then you need to repeat .*\n fifty times

Comment: @EdibleMuffin I have added a brief explanation and made a slight change in the RegEx so that you can modify the code to put `<br>` between any number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using string manipulation when using HTML string. Also using BR to break line is not a good idea as well. You should use a block element instead.

```js
var num = `http://url.com
http://url2test.com
http://url3nag.com
http://url4lalala.com
http://url5papapapapa.com
http://url6ddadadadad.com
http://url7etet.com
http://url8testtest.com`;

var content = document.querySelector('.content');

var urls = num.split('\n');
var temp;

for(var i = 0; i< urls.length; i++) {
  if(!temp || (i+1) % 3 === 0) {
    if (temp) content.appendChild(temp);
    temp = document.createElement('div');
  }
  
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.classList.add('link')
  span.innerHTML = urls[i];
  temp.appendChild(span);
}
content.appendChild(temp);
```

```css
.link {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
```

#### Reference:

- [Is it sometimes bad to use <BR />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br)