# line break between buttons in css/html

Tags: html, css, button

I have a screenshot as shown below which I have to replicate in CSS/HTML.

[image]

I have created the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/230/embedded/result/) for the above screenshot. At this moment, buttons are align in a straight line.

The HTML/CSS codes which I have used in order to make the buttons are:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="buttons">
   <button class="add-winner">Add Winder</button>
   <button class="save">Save</button>
   <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.login-page .form .login-form .add-winner {
    border: 1px solid #1173B7;
    background-color: white;
    color: #1173B7;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 25%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}
.login-page .form .login-form .save {
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
    border: 1px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 35%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering, what changes I should make the in HTML/CSS codes above or in the fiddle so that there is a line break between the button as present in the screenshot.

Comment: what buttons do you want the line break between?

Comment: @CoryKleiser If you the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/230/embedded/result/), I want the button to look exactly the same as in the screenshot.

Comment: Ok,l if you would like a line break between see my answer.. That will get you closer to where you want to be. If you update the css to position them like the screen shot you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this. The dirty way would be to add `<br>` to add a line break like this (for best practice, read on):

```
<div class="buttons">
   <button class="add-winner">Add Winder</button>
   <br>
   <button class="save">Save</button>
   <br>
   <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

You could also wrap your buttons in any block level elements, like this:

```
<div class="buttons">
   <div>
      <button class="add-winner">Add Winder</button>
   </div>
   <div>
      <button class="save">Save</button>
   </div>
   <div>
      <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Cancel</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

That would get the job done as well. However the easiest and most efficient way, IMO, would be to set the button's `display: block;` in the css. Here is a code snippet (with your styles included) using `display: block;` which would be the preferred method:

```css
.form {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.form input {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  outline: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form input:focus {
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
}

.login-page .form .login-form a {
  color: #676767;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.login-page .form .login-form .add-winner {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 40%;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #1173B7;
  background-color: white;
  color: #1173B7;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 25%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 6%;
}

.login-page .form .login-form .save {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #C4C4C4;
  border: 1px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 35%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="login-form">
      <div class="buttons container-fluid">
        <button class="add-winner">Add Winder</button>
        <button class="save">Save</button>
        <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Cancel</a>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/991ea8a605.js"></script>
```

As for the styles for your specific situation. You can also add this style to get the Add Winner `button` to line it up on the right side like the screenshot

```
.add-winner{
  position:relative;
  left:40%;
}
```

And as far as the bottom white you can override that by adding this style to your css:

```
html{
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
}
```

The reason you had the white space at the bottom is you set the `background-color` on your `.login-page` class which stopped short of the bottom of the page.

Comment: I will take your answer. I have one more question. I am wondering if there is any way, I can remove the white spacing from the bottom in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/230/embedded/result/). I want the white spacing at the bottom to have `background-color:#BFBFBF`

Comment: At this moment, there is white spacing at the bottom in the fiddle. I just want to get rid of it and replaced it by `background-color:#BFBFBF`

Comment: @user5447339 I have updated my answer to include the style to override the bottom white space.. Please have a look

Comment: Never, EVER use `<br>` for styling purposes! That's what CSS is for. "br elements must be used only for line breaks that are actually part of the content" https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element

Comment: Yeah, better to use `display: block;` Just providing all options.

Comment: I would argue against the `<br>` tag. It is meaningless from a semantic point of view can not be style or spacing adjusted and forces a line break. If you decided you don't wan't the line break in certain scenarios (thing screen width, orientation etc) you're stuck with it.

Comment: Please consider simplifying your 2nd example. Most of it is irrelevant and bootstrap is overkill.

Comment: @JonP... Yeah I can simplify.. I just copied and pasted his code from jsfiddle and added my styles. I'm not sure why bootstrap is included; I don't think he's using it.

Comment: I'm sorry, He is using it; very minimally though.

Comment: @Rob I am wondering, if you can update in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nc2djn5p/230/embedded/result/) **the way is better to give the line breaks between breaks**. At this moment, I am seeing <br> tags a short-term solution.

Comment: @user5447339 I have the preferred solution in my code snippet. I’m setting the display to block which will cause the line breaks.

Comment: @CoryKleiser Are the answers in the code snippet updated one ?

Comment: @user5447339 yeah that’s the updated one. I updated it on fiddle real quick for you too. I’m using display: block; instead of <br> which is much better practice. I’ve also move the buttons around to get them closer to what the screenshot looks like

Comment: @user5447339 I did forget to add the last style that will fix the unwanted white space for you in the fiddle. You can go ahead and paste it in from my answer as a remedy.

Comment: @CoryKleiser Thanks for the fiddle. It worked for me. I am wondering if you can add the last style. I tried looking from your answer but I wasn't to find.

Answer (score 1):

you can instead for better HTML structure use a `list`

like

```css
ul {
list-style: none;

}
li {
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="buttons">
   <li><button class="add-winner">Add Winder</button></li>
   <li><button class="save">Save</button></li>
   <li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Cancel</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You don't need a list to make this "responsive".

Comment: @Rob You don't *need* to use a list, you *could* use one. It kind of makes sense from a semantic point of view. It is a list of buttons after all. I don't know if it would be my choice, but it is better than `<br>`

Comment: @JonP He said "for responsitivty use a list". You don't need a list for responsitivty [sic]

Comment: @Rob, you are right , I have updated it for better HTML structure

Comment: @Rob thanks for the comments. I am wondering if g33k user approach is the right way to give a line break between buttons.

Comment: @user5447339 from the HTML structure  prospective,  i think it's better to have document without  line breaks `<br>`

you can check 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1726103/5940860

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Answer (score 1):

use two divs. one for the add winner button and other one to the cancel and save button.then you can align each button easily.as well as use ( **br** ) tag to get a new line

Comment: If you wrap the buttons in a div you don’t need the br tag as a div is a block level element.

Comment: yeah. if we use br tag we can get more space between two buttons nah. that's why i mention it  :)