# button.addEventListener not working in nested for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested, dom-events

I'm working on an engine that creates maps files for a game I made. The game is a text based adventure that uses a grid of spaces to display events like messages, items, quests, enemies etc.

The form I'm working on now will create a grid using buttons as the values are type into the input fields - this creates a better visual representation.

I'm working on this function that does the following.

1. checks if a height has been specified - this way it knows if its drawing a linear room or a rectangular room before anything else is execute
2. if it's a linear room (only width has been specified), it uses the width to create and append buttons to the containing element.
3. if it is rectangular (width and height have been specified), a nested for loop runs which appends x amount of buttons for the width, then y amount of 
   's for the height.
4. when one of these buttons is clicked, it appends another form to the screen. which can then be filled out by the user.

Here is the code for this:

```
    var creategridwidth = function(room)
{
    //store the room in a local variable
    var room = room;
    //while the grid container has children in it
    while(room.subGridContainer.hasChildNodes())
    {
        //remove the children from the container
        room.subGridContainer.removeChild(room.subGridContainer.lastChild);
    }
    //if the room height has already been set
    if(room.heightValue > 0)
    {
        //loop through the amount of rows
        for(var x = 0; x < room.heightValue; x ++)
        {
            //loop through the amount of columns
            for(var y = 0; y < room.widthValue; y ++)
            {
                //create a new button element
                var button = document.createElement('button')
                //assign the button element to the grid class
                button.setAttribute("class", "grid");
                //add an event listener for on click to view input information
                button.addEventListener('click', function() 
                {
                    console.log("click")
                    //run add space input function to add the html form to the page.
                    addspaceinput(room);
                }, false);
                //display the button as inline block so that they are side by side
                button.style.display = "inline-block";
                //append the button to the grid container
                room.subGridContainer.appendChild(button);                          
            }
            //when the row has been added, add a line break to start the next lie.
            room.subGridContainer.innerHTML += "<br>";
        }
    //if the height has not already been set
    } else {
        //loop through the width of the room
        for(var z = 0; z < room.widthValue; z ++)
        {
            //create a new button element
            var button = document.createElement('button')
            //assign the button element to the grid class
            button.setAttribute("class", "grid");
            //add an event listener for on click to view input information
            button.addEventListener('click', function() 
            {
                console.log("click")
                //run add space input function to add the html form to the page.
                addspaceinput(room);
            }, false);
            //display the button as inline block so that they are side by side
            button.style.display = "inline-block";
            //append the button to the grid container
            room.subGridContainer.appendChild(button);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the part I'm having trouble with is the event listener happening in the nest for loop.

For example:

```
        for(var z = 0; z < room.widthValue; z ++)
        {
            //create a new button element
            var button = document.createElement('button')
            //assign the button element to the grid class
            button.setAttribute("class", "grid");
            //add an event listener for on click to view input information
            button.addEventListener('click', function() 
            {
                console.log("click")
                //run add space input function to add the html form to the page.
                addspaceinput(room);
            }, false);
            //display the button as inline block so that they are side by side
            button.style.display = "inline-block";
            //append the button to the grid container
            room.subGridContainer.appendChild(button);
        }
```

I can see this log appear in the console, this works fine.
However:

```
        for(var x = 0; x < room.heightValue; x ++)
        {
            //loop through the amount of columns
            for(var y = 0; y < room.widthValue; y ++)
            {
                //create a new button element
                var button = document.createElement('button')
                //assign the button element to the grid class
                button.setAttribute("class", "grid");
                //add an event listener for on click to view input information
                button.addEventListener('click', function() 
                {
                    console.log("click")
                    //run add space input function to add the html form to the page.
                    addspaceinput(room);
                }, false);
                //display the button as inline block so that they are side by side
                button.style.display = "inline-block";
                //append the button to the grid container
                room.subGridContainer.appendChild(button);                          
            }
            //when the row has been added, add a line break to start the next lie.
            room.subGridContainer.innerHTML += "<br>";
        }
```

This gives absolutely no behavior. I'm not sure how to move forward with this.
I'd appreciate any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
room.subGridContainer.innerHTML += "<br>";
```

When you assign to `innerHTML`, the existing `innerHTML` is retrieved, *the element is cleared*, and then the new concatenated `innerHTML` string is parsed into the DOM. So, any variables referencing elements inside will be lost, including elements that used to have event listeners.

```js
const button = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
button.textContent = 'click';
button.onclick = () => console.log('clicked');

// the next line will break the listener:
document.body.innerHTML += '<br>';
```

Explicitly append elements instead:

```
room.subGridContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
```

Another option would be to `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```
room.subGridContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<br>');
```

But if you want the button to be on its own line, it would be better to put it inside a block element, rather than append `br`s:

```
var div = room.subGridContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
var button = div.appendChild(document.createElement('button'));
// etc
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thanks for the quick response also! I had no idea about this. Will definitely make sure to note this for the future! 

Thanks again!

Comment: @JonathanHinds A better option would be to wrap buttons in a block level element. `<br/>` in some opinions are considered as bad practice. **[Why BR is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br)**

Comment: @JonathanHinds You can take reference from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o4g8y1un/2/). CertainPerformance, if you can also add this approach in your answer, it would be great. If not, no issues

Comment: @Rajesh so, by this do you mean creating something such as a div, and appending the button to that?

Comment: @JonathanHinds Yes. That is exactly what I mean. I even created a JSFiddle **(http://jsfiddle.net/o4g8y1un/2/)** for your reference.