# How to get rid of 'key' error while using map in React?

Tags: reactjs, key, array-map

Everyone know this error: `Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop` But what if I have array of strings that I want to render in my paragraph with 
 at the end?

```
return(
    <p>
    {array.map(string => {
        return <>{string}<br/></>
    })}
    </p>
)
```

As you can see I'm literally returning only text with `<br/>` at the end, I don't have place or need for a key. How can I get rid of this error? Wrapping every phrase in `<span>` is not an option.

Comment: This might be an xy problem. Why are you using `<br />` here? Depending on what you're doing, maybe drop the `p` and use a `ul` or `li` which is the correct semantic for lists of items. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726073/is-it-sometimes-bad-to-use-br#:~:text=The%20main%20reason%20for%20not,space%20the%20blocks%20out%20properly.)

Comment: I actually don't need list. I have a normal paragraph, that I get from server as array, each element means that new line supposed to be there, therefore `<br/>`. I don't want react to listen to it, since I'm literally printing several lines into same paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When React renders changes, before pushing changes to the DOM, it uses the [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html) to intelligently decide which changes it needs to push to keep things efficient, as DOM manipulation can be an expensive operation.

When rendering a collection of child elements, let's say some `<li>` elements, React will complain when a unique `key` prop has not been provided. The reason why it needs this prop is so it can perform the intelligent decision I mentioned above.

Oh and as @JBallin mentioned in the comments, you should define the `key` prop as a string, as it is not recommended to use the index for it:

```js
return(
  <p>
    {array.map((string, index) => <React.Fragment key={index.toString()}>{string}<br/></React.Fragment>)}
  </p>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use map index for key of paragraph like this:

```
return(
    <p>
    {array.map((string,index)=> {
        return <React.fragment key={index}>{string}<br/></React.fragment>
    })}
    </p>
)
```

Comment: Note that React [doesn't recommend](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) using indices for keys.

Comment: if your data haven't an unique key you must use map index or generate id for every items!

Comment: You might want to be careful when trying to "...generate id for every items". Every time a re-render is about to occur and a new set of keys are used, React doesn't know to optimise. It's best to use strings that don't change to leverage performance optimisation during DOM diffing.